# jpa entity mapping couple tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I had entity for JSON parsing

```
    @Entity
    public class Product{
    private int productId;
    private String productName;
    private BigDecimal productPrice;
    private int productVendorId;
    private String productVendorName;
    private int productCategoryId;
    private String productCategoryName;
    //getters setters here
```

created 3 tables in dataBase:
products (product_id, product_name,product_price, product_vendor_id), product_category_id);
vendors(vendor_id, vendor_name); categories (category_id, category_name);
in 1st table product_vendor_id fk -> vendor_id pk in vendors and product_category_id fk -> category_id pk in categories
i tried something like this:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "products, schema = "market")
    public class Product
    @Id
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false, name = "product_id")
    private int Id;
    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String productName;
    @Column(name = "product_price")
    private BigDecimal productPrice;
    @Column(name = "product_vendor_id")
    private int productVendorId;
    @Columnt(table = "vendors", name = "vendor_name")
    private String vendor_name;
    @Column(name = "product_category_id")
    private int productCategoryId;
    @Column(table = "categories", name = "category_name")
    private String productCategorName;
    //getters setters here
```

received alot of errors: like i have not category_name column in products table etc. this error i received when used

```
     @Table(name = "products", schema = "market" )
     @SecondaryTables({@SecondaryTable(name = "vendors", schema = "market"),
     @SecondaryTable(name = "categories", schema = "market")})
     @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
     public class Product {
     ....
     @JoinColumn(name = "product_vendor_id", referencedColumnName = "vendor_id")
     private int productVendorID;
     @JoinColumn(table = "vendors", name = "vendor_name")
     private String productVendorName;
     @JoinColumn(name = "product_category_id", referencedColumnName = 
     "product_category_id")
     private int productCategoryID;
     @JoinColumn(table = "categories",  name = "category_name")
     private String productCategoryName;
```

exception:

```
     Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column 
     product0_1_.product_id doesn't exist
     Hint: There may have been a link to the "product0_.product_id" column
     Position: 705
```

how can i map this entity on 3 tables? 
upd: i don't want separate this entity, i need this for deserialize my json object too, just want reuse this entity on different operations.
example of json

```
   {"productID":"1111111","productName":"Cool product","productPrice":"99.99","productVendorName":"Some store","productVendorID":"1337","productCategoryName":"Food","productCategoryID":"1"}
```

Comment: A `@JoinColumn` is for use where you have a relation. Your classes have no relation. Any basic JPA doc would explain such things

Comment: You have to read a JPA tutorial.

Comment: `@Column(name = "product_vendor_id")
    private int productVendorID;
    @Column(table = "vendors", name = "vendor_name")
    private String productVendorName;

    @Column(name = "product_category_id")
    private int productCategoryID;
    @Column(table = "categories", name = "category_name")`      
    private String productCategoryName; same issue anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are 3 separate tables, you would want to create three separate entity classes. 
Also I'm assuming vendors and category tables will have one to many relation to product.
Try below code:

**Product**:

```
@Entity
public class Product {
  @Id
  private int productId;
  private String productName;
  private BigDecimal productPrice;
  private String productVendorName;
  private String productCategoryName;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "productCategoryId")
  private Category category;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "productVendorId")
  private Vendors vendor;
}
```

**Category**:

```
@Entity
public class Category {
  @Id
  private Integer categoryId;
  private String categoryName;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
  @NotEmpty
  private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Vendors:**

```
@Entity
public class Vendors {
  @Id
  private int vendorId;
  private String vendorName;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vendor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
  @NotEmpty
  private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Though, I would recommend using above approach, if you still want to have single entity class and 3 separate table with redudant data then use below:

```
@Entity
@SecondaryTables({ @SecondaryTable(name = "vendors"), @SecondaryTable(name = "categories") })
public class Product {
  @Id
  private int productId;
  private String productName;
  private BigDecimal productPrice;
  private String productVendorName;
  private String productCategoryName;
  @Column(table = "categories")
  private Integer categoryId;
  @Column(table = "categories")
  private String categoryName;
  @Column(table = "vendors")
  private int vendorId;
  @Column(table = "vendors")
  private String vendorName;
}
```

The id column of the main table will be present in all the 3 tables and used for joining them.

Comment: oh sorry, i didn't write my full question. i want use this 1 entity for deserialize my json object too, so i want reuse it few times w/o separation
is it possible?

Comment: Can you please let me know what's the purpose of having 3 separate tables when you are going to have just one entity class? If you want your data normalised you need to have separate tables and for that separate entity classes.
If data normalisation is not your priority, consider creating a single table and a single entity class on it.

Comment: I'm using this pojo class for ObjectMapper, and i have particular json construction. So my question was: "can i use same pojo class for jpa entity or not?"

Comment: If you want your data normalised and in three separate tables then no, you can't use the same class as entity. Also, would you mind including a sample json of yours in the question?

Comment: thank you. got my answer.
added json string to head question.

Comment: So you are going with a single table approach? Just put @entity on your pojo class. Though, I would recommend using 3 separate classes as this approach will result in data redundancy. Also, it's you who can accept the answer, not me or anyone else :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184180/discussion-between-yegor-saliev-and-aditya-narayan-dixit).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for poor wording of the question, just didn't know how to explane what i wanted.
All what i need just add @transient annotations for fields which i don't have in products table, and separate it like accepted answer was suggested.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products", schema = "store" )
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Product {
@Id
@Column(updatable = false, nullable = false, name = "product_id")
private int productId;
@Column(name = "product_name")
private String productName;
@Column(name = "product_price")
private BigDecimal productPrice;
@Transient
private String productVendorName;
@Transient
private String productCategoryName;
@Transient
private int vendorId;
@Transient
private int categoryId;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "product_category_id")
private Category category;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "product_vendor_id")
private Vendor vendor;
}
```

for vendors table entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vendors", schema = "store")
public class Vendor {
@Id
@Column(name = "vendor_id")
private int vendorId;
@Column(name = "vendor_name")
private String vendorName;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "vendor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
orphanRemoval = true)
@NotNull
private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and for categories

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories", schema = "store")
public class Category {
@Id
@Column(name = "category_id")
private Integer categoryId;
@Column(name = "category_name")
private String categoryName;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
orphanRemoval = true)
@NotNull
private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Wanted to leave here full answer on my question, maybe someone will need it later
Just check some problems with toString. Use it only in Product.class and better make 2 versions for print json and jpa.